# How to Remove the cell's Large Margins in PyCharm's Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Recently, I've been working with Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm and have encountered an issue that doesn't arise when using the IDE in its regular mode. Typically, I can split my screen vertically and efficiently work with two panels side-by-side without any loss of code visibility. However, when working with Jupyter notebooks, the cell structure, which includes significantly wide margins on the left side, presents a problem. These margins lead to a loss of approximately 25% of my screen space when using the split-screen feature, significantly impacting my productivity.

Is there a way to address this issue, such as adjusting the cell size or modifying the cell margins, to reclaim the lost screen space?